# Align the drawableEnd image to the end of the text on the button

Tags: android, button

How to align the drawableEnd image to the end of the text on the button? Button width set to match_parent.
I want to get the following button:

[[image]]

I'm sorry, but I couldn't find a solution and can't give any code examples.

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to make custom and give click event to parent layout button(try this code it will work for you)

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/value_40"
        android:background="@color/text1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/cross"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>
        
        
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```